# Difference b/w .htaccess and example.com.conf

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess

I have a example.com.conf and .htaccess for example.com site.

When I place this following content in .htacess file

```
RewriteEngine on
# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

it works. The same rule doesn't work inside the VirtualHost in example.com.conf which is up using sites-enabled in apache ? It throws "Bad Request" errors when using example.com.conf

What is the reason, why is it treated differently ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `htaccess` file is basically another way of configuring directives in an identical context to a `<Directory>` section at that location.

The reason this doesn't work for you is that the `mod_rewrite` configuration is sensitive to context - what you have there requires some adjustment to work within the `<VirtualHost>` context instead of an `.htaccess` or `<Directory>` context.

To get the failures to stop, you should just need to switch from `RewriteRule . index.php` to `RewriteRule . /index.php` - but the context change would also break your use of `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}`, since it requires the request to have already been mapped to a filesystem location.  So I'd say just put the rules inside a `<Directory>` block within your `<VirtualHost>`.